# How to get the counted values with a comma separator as a single row value

Tags: mysql

Using the following query I getting the result like how much the players in the table, but now I also want which players are in the same table, and show those players id with a comma separator.

```
select gt.id,
       bcc.min_coins,
       bcc.max_coins,
       (
          SELECT count(gtp.id)
            FROM game_table_players gtp
                 LEFT JOIN game_rounds gr
                 ON gr.id = gtp.game_round_id
           WHERE gt.id = gtp.game_table_id
             AND gtp.quit<>1 AND gr.finish=0
       ) AS no_of_players,
       IFNULL
       (
           (
               SELECT game_started
                 FROM game_rounds gr
                WHERE gr.game_table_id = gt.id
                  AND gr.finish=0
           ),0
        ) AS game_started
from game_tables gt
     LEFT JOIN pickdeck_category pc
          ON pc.id = gt.pickdeck_category_id
     LEFT JOIN bet_coin_category bcc
          ON bcc.id = gt.bet_coin_category_id
where gt.pickdeck_category_id =1
ORDER BY created_date
LIMIT 0,20
```

---

[image: Current result from given query]

[image: Expected]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function you are looking for is `GROUP_CONCAT`. See the documentation:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

In your example you can just create one more subquery (example below). Or `JOIN` it in a standard way to the original query.

```
...
(
      SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(gtp.id)
          FROM game_table_players gtp
          LEFT JOIN game_rounds gr ON gr.id = gtp.game_round_id
      WHERE gt.id = gtp.game_table_id
          AND gtp.quit<>1 AND gr.finish=0
) AS players,
...
```

Note the comment on `NULL` handling in `GROUP_CONCAT`. If you want to show zeros when there aren't any players present, you might want to use `COALESCE(GROUP_CONCAT(gtp.id), 0)` instead.