# Manipulate Arrays in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I fetch the Result from two tables using join. It gives me result like.I want to manipulate results according to like:

A question name having multiple results.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [question_id] => 1
            [option] => kk
            [created_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [updated_at] => 2016-01-04 17:19:47
            [deleted_at] => 
            [question] => whats ur name
            [status] => 0
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [question_id] => 1
            [option] => bb
            [created_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [updated_at] => 2016-01-04 17:19:47
            [deleted_at] => 
            [question] => whats ur name
            [status] => 0
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [question_id] => 2
            [option] => anish
            [created_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [updated_at] => 2016-01-04 18:38:38
            [deleted_at] => 
            [question] => whats ur father name
            [status] => 0
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [question_id] => 2
            [option] => satish
            [created_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [updated_at] => 2016-01-04 18:38:38
            [deleted_at] => 
            [question] => whats ur father name
            [status] => 0
        )

)
```

Here is my Code:

```
public function question_get() {
        $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('hbp_question_options');
        $this->db->join('hbp_questions', 'hbp_questions.id = hbp_question_options.question_id');
        $query = $this->db->get();

        $result = $query->result();


        foreach($result as $results)
        {


        }
```

I dont want duplicate result.I want result with question name with their options.

Comment: How you are getting this array?

Comment: change your SQL query.

Comment: use group by in your query it's avoid duplicate

Comment: My Query is like: Select * From Question LEFT JOIN Question_options ON Question.question.id = Question_options.question_id

Comment: You either need to join your `option` values in your query, using something like `GROUP_CONCAT()`, or use php to loop over your object and merge them.

Comment: I dont know how can I manage

Comment: Well first thing is you need to determine how you want them combined - as a csv, as a nested array/object under `option`, ...? Can you show what your desired outcome would look like, as well as your php/mysql code you use to get your results.

Comment: see this, may be it ll help you.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34238413/how-to-get-the-counted-values-with-comma-seprator-as-single-row-value

Comment: I want Simply show result like:Question Name with their options

Comment: Select * From Question LEFT JOIN Question_options ON Question.question.id = Question_options.question_id  GROUP BY Question.id use this

Comment: @user2830034 the problem with doing `GROUP BY Question .id` without doing a `GROUP_CONCAT()` on `option`, is that you will only get 1 value of `option`, where the OP wants all the values.

Comment: So is your question on how to show the results **OR** to change/manipulate your php object? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34605099/manipulate-arrays-in-php#comment56955897_34605099 - Currently your question is to change/manipulate your php object, not show the results. In either case you need to show more of what you are trying to do, what you want to do, and why those are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. `GROUP_CONCAT` (as mentioned above in comments). Something along the lines of:

   ```
   $this->db->select('hbp_questions.*, GROUP_CONCAT(hbp_question_options.option) as options');
   ```
2. rebuild the array with the options grouped together.

   ```
   $grouped_results = [];    
   foreach($results as $result){
       if (!isset($grouped_results[$result['question_id'])) {
           $grouped_results['questionid'] = [
               'question_id' => $result['question_id'],
               'question' => $result['question'],
               'status' => $result['status'],
               'options' => [],
           ];
       }
       $grouped_results['question_id']['options'][$result['id']] = $result['option'];
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you fix your *SQL Query* instead of filtering it using PHP. It really might slow your application down if you have large data to retrieve.

But if you insist to do it through PHP, this code may help you.

```
$ids = array();

// $fetchResult is the result of your array on your post.
$finalResult = array_filter($fetchResult, function($obj) use (&$ids)
{
    //$id = $obj['id'] || $obj.id;
    $id = $obj['id']; // Or in your case, you might need to access it like `$obj.id`
    if (!in_array($id, $ids))
    {
        $ids[] = $id;
        return $obj;
    }
});
var_dump($finalResult);
```